Source of Chofetz Chaim’s Statement on Every Nation Having Translated Bibles and Believing in the Revelation at Mount Sina
In the Sefer Taharas Yisroel (chapter 1), the Chofetz Chaim claims that all nations (in his time) believed in the revelation at Mount Sinai recorded in the Bible and had copies of the Bible in their own language.
The phrase "all nations on earth from one end to the other" suggests that he was referring to every nation without exception.
Furthermore, the chapter's context suggests that he refers to every nation. He aims to highlight the utter foolishness of those who reject the Torah, as all nations accept its story. His argument loses much of its force if the Bible is acknowledged solely by Christianity and Islam rather than universally.
What is the source of this?
I find it hard to believe that Hindus, Buddhists, and all the Indigenous peoples of Africa, South America, and Australia had copies of the Bible, let alone believe it.
He does cite a verse in Parshas Nitzavim which states that all nations will acknowledge Israel's suffering as a consequence of abandoning their covenant with God. However, employing this as evidence to discredit Torah skeptics is circular reasoning. It claims they are foolish for disputing something supposedly recognized by all nations, yet the sole claim to its universal acknowledgment is the Torah itself.

I don't know, if we include the fact that the Christians spread the Torah round the world in the form of the old testament, he's prob not too far off

The awareness of the Old Testament of the groups I mentioned is akin to your awareness of the Koran, which I assume means nothing to you. The roughly 1.5 billion combined Hindus and Buddhists neither believe in nor possess copies of the Bible. Moreover, the more I think about it, the acceptance of the Bible by Christianity and Islam does not strengthen Jewish faith. Although they believe the narrative, they now hold that Jews no longer have the covenant, making it a futile argument to carefully observe the Torah laws, which was the purpose of his essay.

I recall reading in anti-frum literature published in the time the CC said the above that Hindus and Buddhists had translations of the Torah and that the Buddhist belief of the time was that it is possible the Torah was given on Har Sinai

@Bpsb your question only mentions that Chafetz Chaim is holding they believe in Sinai, which Christians and Muslims do too. Also, I'm not 100% sure you are right. Schmerel has made a point, and that's not the first time I've heard it either. There is a lot of Mary worship in the far east, which implies a Bible somewhere or other. Make a stronger case, as your claim that 1.5 billion "don't believe or have copies of" is hearsay and doesn't prove anything.

@Bpsb "the acceptance of the Bible by Christianity and Islam does not strengthen Jewish faith." In this regard it is worth seeing the censored parts of the Rambam in Hilchos Melachim https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.11.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en "Ultimately, all the deeds of Jesus of Nazareth and that Ishmaelite who arose after him will only serve to prepare the way for Mashiach's coming and the improvement of the entire world, motivating the nations to serve God together..."

@Bpsb "The entire world has already become filled with the mention of Mashiach, Torah, and mitzvot. These matters have been spread to the furthermost islands... Saying: 'These mitzvot were true, but were already negated'... When the true Messianic king will arise and prove successful, his position becoming exalted and uplifted, they will all return and realize that their ancestors endowed them with a false heritage..."
...

Did any of you have a chance to read the context of his essay? In my opinion, the only way to justify what he is saying is that he is using a "noble lie" to promote Torah observance.

As I am going through his writings, I see lots of similarly bold claims that seem to be without sources. I will post some more soon.

Here is a copy of a post I submitted on the "r/hinduism" on reddit:
